# Key for open hint window in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

See the pic:

[image]

In netbeans it's atl+enter.

Comment: Exactly! Maybe you can post it as an answer? :)

Answer (score 5):

Eclipse uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open the code completion popup, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for a quick-fix popup on an issue.